# How to reference a report from a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to reference a report object in some VBA code from a form object in Access 2010.  I understand that in a report, I can use the syntax `Reports![report name]` to reference the report named "report_name", but this does not seem to work from within form code.

So my question is: How can I reference a report object from within VBA code for a form object?

Comment: The Reports collection includes only OPEN reports, so Reports![report name] will only refer to the desired report if it is already open. You can refer to unopen reports with the AllForms collection, but you can't do the same things with them that you can with open reports.

Answer (score 4):

Here is code for the click event of a command button on my form.  It opens a report named *rptFoo*, then refers to the open form to retrieve its name property and `Debug.Print` that name to the Immediate Window.

```vb
Private Sub cmdReferenceReport_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFoo", acViewPreview
    Debug.Print Reports!rptFoo.name '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
End Sub
```

Here's another way to do it.

```vb
Private Sub cmdReferenceReport_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFoo", acViewPreview
    Dim rpt As Report
    Set rpt = Reports!rptFoo
    Debug.Print rpt.name
    Set rpt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you once again. Your posts are very helpful to me today.

Answer (score 1):

@HansUp when passing the report name as a string variable (rather than a string literal as you have in your code), I receive the runtime error 2451 - "The report name 'reportName' you entered is misspelled or refers to a report that isn't open or doesn't exist." Like the OP, I'm also using MS Access 2010.

My solution for referencing a report from a form using a string variable for the report name is to use parenthesis syntax: Reports(string report name variable here)

Example:

```
Public Sub Set_Report_RecordSource(reportName As String, datasourceQueryName As String)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Purpose: Sets a report's recordsource programmatically. Especially useful
    ' for a report that is used by many forms.
    ' Params:
    '   reportName = Report whose RecordSource needs to be set.
    '   datasourceQueryName = The query name that will return records to display
    '   by the specified report (reportName).
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    DoCmd.OpenReport reportName:=reportName, View:=acViewDesign
    Reports(reportName).RecordSource = datasourceQueryName
    DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acReport, ObjectName:=reportName, Save:=acSaveYes
End Sub
```